# If I get stuck on a Codingbat exercise, which Stack Exchange forum would be appropriate for getting assistance so I can understand and move on?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, students

Codingbat.com provides interactive coding exercises, and I'm using it to practice my Java. I do however want to understand where I went wrong with human aid here and there.

Which forum is most appropriate as I don't want to post off-topic?

Comment: SE isn't a collection of forums.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### If...

If you are stuck with a programming problem, that you looked online to try and find what you were looking for and are able to show and proove that you made the necessary effort to find your answer without success, you can post a valid, well formulated (according to the site rules) question on Stack Overflow.

Make sure the question is not a duplicate, make sure the questions fits the Q&A standrard and make sure that it is not a "Plz code that for me" question.

### Else...

You judge it doesn't belong on the first site ? You feel like you want advice on how to improve your current code and have questions about how you could make it better on different points ? Code review is for you. Make sure you read the Help Center what can I ask here section before posting.

### Finally...

If you judge the question is more about opinion, or that it doesn't fit on the website aboves because it doesn't quite fit the Q&A format then maybe stack exchange isn't for you. **All the sites are very strict about Q&A format and posting rules so simply putting a question and "asking what is wrong with the codez" is very unlikely to get a good reception here.**

Comment: Thank you. In your If... section: are there relevant places on the web where I can check online? The best I know of is Yahoo Answers which isn't skewed toward code so I don't want to come back saying I looked when I didn't know the best places to look before approaching Stack.

Comment: @WarrenvanRooyen Since this is CodingBat, I know you're working in either Java or Python. Both of these languages have documentation online for their standard libraries. At a bare minimum, skim those first. Especially since CodingBat breaks down their problems in sections based on what concept they're trying to get you to work on; looking for tutorials on those topics would be good too (it'll also potentially give you more things to consider and read documentation on)

Comment: @warren What dennis said. Plus make sure it is not already on the network. This happens to often. a lot of questions have already been asked!!!

Comment: Thanks so much guys. I really appreciate that. It's so wonderful to know that I've got all the support I need to study independently. Thanks again!

Comment: @DennisMeng Great guess! It's Java :D

Comment: @WarrenvanRooyen Wasn't a guess; I've been on CodingBat before too.

Comment: @DennisMeng. I love it. What a great resource to learn with!

Comment: @warren Glad I could help! :) dont forget to mark this question as answered if you found out what you were looking for.

Comment: Done!Done!Done!:D